# How can I use shift or ctrl key without openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, map-drawing, mapguide, ol-interaction

I want to verify if <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed to make my own multiselection.

I use a digitizer to draw polygon, rectangle, etc... to make selection from geometry on server-side (with mapguide api).

My problem is when I want to make a multiselection, I need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and draw my rectangle for example. After I send to the server my rectangle geometry and that I'm in multiselection because of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or shift key pressed.

But when I press shift and I want to draw, I see my pointer of drawing but on first click, my draw stop.

And when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and I want to draw, I see my pointer of drawing too but when I click, nothing happend.

I have disable map interactions :

```js
me._map = new ol.Map({
interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
  doubleClickZoom: false,
  shiftDragZoom: false,
  altShiftDragRotate: false,
  keyboard: false,
  pinchRotate: false,
  pinchZoom: false,

}),
controls: [],
layers: [layer],
target: me._options.target,
view: new ol.View(options)
});
```

I want to do this since I'm drawing with my digitizer:

```js
on(document, "keydown", function (event)
    {
      if (event.keyCode == keys.SHIFT || event.keycode == keys.CTRL)
        me._isShiftDown = true;
    });
    on(document, "keyup", function (event)
    {
      if (event.keyCode == keys.SHIFT || event.keycode == keys.CTRL)
        me._isShiftDown = false;
    });
    window.onblur = function ()
    {
      me._isShiftDown = false;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement, so I managed to solve it that way:

```
var shiftKeyPressed;
function initSelectOnBoxControl (){ 
selectOnBoxInt = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
  //  condition  : ol.events.condition.always,
    condition : function(e){
        console.log(e.browserEvent.shiftKey);
        shiftKeyPressed = e.browserEvent.shiftKey;
        return true;//always return true but need to set whether shift key is pressed or not
    },
    style      : new ol.style.Style({
        fill       : new ol.style.Fill({
            color      : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
        }),
        stroke     : new ol.style.Stroke({
            color    : 'red',
            width    : 3
    })
  })
});  
selectOnBoxInt.on('boxend',function(e){
alert("action for selection here. Shift key is pressed:"+shiftKeyPressed);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this answer, I have resolved my problem making a condition in my draw interaction and setting shiftKeyPressed in global variable like this :

```
var shiftKeyPressed = false;
    me._draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      condition: function (e)
      {
        shiftKeyPressed = e.browserEvent.shiftKey;
        return true;
        //always return true to use the interaction with key pressed or not
      },
      type: type,
      geometryFunction: geometryFunction,
      maxPoints: maxPoints
    });
```

And I send it in my callback:

```
me._draw.on("drawend", function (event)
    {
      me._map.removeInteraction(me._draw);
      me._draw = null;
      var geometry = event.feature.getGeometry();

      if (me._callback != null)
      {
        callback.call(me._scope || me, geometry, shiftKeyPressed);
      }
    });
```